# If $A$ is a Dedekind cut, then we define $-A=\{r\in \Bbb Q:\exists t\notin A; t\lt -r\}.$ Let $O=\{x\in \Bbb Q:x\lt 0\}$ then show that $A+(-A)=O.$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

If $A$ is a Dedekind cut, then we define $-A=\{r\in \Bbb Q:\exists t\notin A; t\lt -r\}.$ Let $O=\{x\in \Bbb Q:x\lt 0\}$ then show that $A+(-A)=O.$

The proof, I encountered was :

> The general strategy is to show that $A+(-A)\subset O$ and $O\subset A+(-A).$ It is easy to show the former inclusion. We try to show the later inclusion.
>
> We fix  $o\in O$ then we must try to find  $a \in A$ and $b\in -A$ so that $a + b = o,$ so that we can conclude the required inclusion.  Set $\epsilon= |o|/2 = -o/2.$  Now choose a rational number $t\notin  A$  with the property that $t-\epsilon \in  A.$ (Here we are relying on properties of a cut. In particular, we could show that if no such $t$ existed then either $A =\Bbb  Q$ or $A = \phi,$ which is never possible if $A$ is a cut.) Now the fact that $ t \notin A$ implies $-(t + \epsilon) \in A.$  Then $$o = -2\epsilon= -(t + \epsilon)+(t -\epsilon)= -A + A,$$ and we conclude $O \subset -A + A.$ This proves $O=A+(-A).$

However, I dont understand how at all they assert, that :

> Set $\epsilon= |o|/2 = -o/2.$  Now choose a rational number $t\notin  A$  with the property that $t-\epsilon \in  A.$

The reason they gave is:

> Here we are relying on properties of a cut. In particular, we could show that if no such $t$ existed then either $A =\Bbb  Q$ or $A = \phi,$ which is never possible if $A$ is a cut.

I dont understand how can they really show that if such a $t$ does not exist then $A =\Bbb  Q$ or $A = \phi.$ If such a $t$ does not exist, then it simply means that $\forall t\notin A,$ we have $t-\epsilon\notin A.$ But I really, don't know why this means that $A=\phi$ or $A=\Bbb Q.$ Any clarification regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will suffice to show that if no such $t$ exists and $A \neq \mathbf{Q}$, then $A$ is empty. Since $A \neq \mathbf{Q}$, there is some rational $r \not\in A$. By the properties of Dedekind cuts, we then have $s \not\in A$ for all rationals $ s \geq r $.

We have assumed that for all $t \not\in A$ it follows that $t - \epsilon \not\in A$. Thus we have $r - \epsilon \not\in A$, which in turn gives $(r - \epsilon) - \epsilon = r - 2 \epsilon \not\in A$, and so on. In general, for any positive integer $n$ we have $r - n\epsilon\not\in A$. Let $s$ be a rational satisfying $s < r$ and choose a positive integer $n$ large enough so that $r - n\epsilon < s$. Since $r - n\epsilon \not\in A$, it follows that $s \not\in A$.

We have now shown that no rational number belongs to $A$, i.e. that $A$ is empty.

Comment: I think the explanation would be more smooth, if you avoid using $s$ for two different purposes. Btw, +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the contrapositive: if $t-\varepsilon \in A$ then $t \in A$. Now suppose $A$ is non-empty and take $t\in A$, we have that $t +\varepsilon - \varepsilon \in A$ so $t + \varepsilon \in A$. Procede insuctivly to show that for every $ n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $t + n\varepsilon \in A$. Use the fact that $A$ is a Dedekind cut to conclude $A=\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: "If $t-\epsilon\in A,$ then $t\in A$" -How do you say that? Is it the contrapositive of some statement ? Then for which statement are you taking the contrapositive?

Comment: You know that if $t$ is not in $A$ then $t - \varepsilon$ is not in $A$.